# Is there a way to programmatically perform a factory reset on an Android device?

Tags: android

Understanding how incredibly dangerous this question is, I'd like to know if it is possible to programmatically issue a factory reset, as available in Droid and G1.  Does anyone know how this is implemented?  Is this implemented using the standard Android SDK, a Motorola-specific function, or something else?

Answer (score 12):

You may use the `WipeData()` method in DevicePolicyManager, which will erase all user data:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Available since Android 2.2

Close enough?

Comment: Not available in Android 11+

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `DevicePolicyManager` method `wipeData()` to reset the device to factory settings. This is useful if the device is lost or stolen. Often the decision to wipe the device is the result of certain conditions being met. For example, you can use `setMaximumFailedPasswordsForWipe()` to state that a device should be wiped after a specific number of failed password attempts.

You wipe data as follows:
Java:

```
DevicePolicyManager dpm;
dpm.wipeData(0);
```

Kotlin:

```
private lateinit var dpm: DevicePolicyManager
dpm.wipeData(0)
```

[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) is the site refrence

Comment: Not available in Android 11+